# Why isn't my program playing an audio clip?

Tags: java

Trying to loop an audio clip. Look right but i hear nothing.

Does local audio clip have to have the extension ".au"? or can i play aiff, mp3 or wav for example?

I'm really sorry if this is not properly explaned. I'm really new to this.

Tried to play sounds on my hard drive (.wav) (put in the same folder as my java program) AND of the internet.

An input dialog pops up and asks for an audio clip. Works fine. Here the user is supposed to write either a local file name or a web address.

I write (for local files) "file:myAudioclip.wav" or (for internet) "https://www....) but nothing plays.

```
import java.applet.*;   //Importerar necessary packages
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class AudioClip2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
   MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
// Handling errors 
      String filnamn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Audio clip?");
// This is where I write what clip I wanna play
      URL u = new URL(filnamn); 
//  Create a URL for my clip
      AudioClip a = Applet.newAudioClip(u);
      a.loop();
//Looping AudioClip a 
      Thread.sleep(10000);  //Create a paus (ignore)
    }    
}
```

Comment: why on earth are you using applet packages?

Comment: "I'm really new to this." - Do you mean you're new to programming in general? If so please DO NOT start with UI and stuff like that (playing audio files etc.) right away. You're in for a lot of headaches that way. First get a good grasp of the basics and then work your way to more complex things.

Comment: This might help: [How to play an Audio file using Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/play-audio-file-using-java/).